# Celery chain not working on django

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

My purpose is call two task sequentially

When task1 is done call task2. I have made this until now

For execute my task in sequential way I use the chain method that I found in documentation. But my task don't need the result of the last task to work as the documentation said. So, I define `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True` to the chain method not take the result from the previous task when executed.

Here is how I'm doing my code

> task.py

```
@app.task
def task1(param):
     ...

@app.task
def task2(param):
    ....
```

> views.py

```
from .task import task1, task2
from celery import chain

chain(task1.delay(identifier), task2.delay(identifier))().get()
```

Every attempt I made i got this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'AsyncResult' and 'AsyncResult'

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is... you should chain *signatures* instead:

`chain(task1.s(identifier), task2.s(identifier))().get()`

from the doc:

> The chain primitive lets us link together signatures so that one is called after the other, essentially forming a chain of callbacks.

For more detail see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#canvas-designing-work-flows

Comment: Like my functions don't take arguments instead use signatures .s() replace for .si() immutable signatures and solve my problem thanks @trinchet